# How do I recover the BIOS on an Acer Aspire ES1-531 after a failed BIOS update

Tags: bios, acer-aspire, recovery

I was hoping I wouldn't have to come to the forums for this, but nothing has worked, so here I am.

Around a year ago or so, I tried to update the BIOS on my laptop (Acer Aspire ES1-531), but the update errored out and it powered off on its own. Afterwards, it wouldn't boot up properly. It would get stuck on a black screen trying to spin the disk drive and read from a USB drive (I know this because the activity light on my drive turns on), before turning itself off and then back on. In other words, my laptop is stuck in a bootloop after the BIOS bricked itself.

I've already tried the FN+Esc method, which doesn't work. I'm able to provide videos of what the laptop is doing if needed, along with file structure of my flash drives.

Comment: Per Acer forum, https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/686475/how-do-i-do-a-bios-recovery-on-an-acer-aspire-es1-531-c3x2, "that is worst thing that can go wrong... I recommend that you do bring your laptop to Acer Services in your country as your laptop is "bricked", and the EEPROM needs to be reprogrammed or often they just replace it, charges won't be much..." You can also try removing the CMOS cell, shorting the contacts, wait for a while, and try rebooting.

Comment: Bro that's my post lol

Comment: Pictures of key moments are better than storage-consuming videos.
The sentence "I've already tried the FN+Esc method, which doesn't work." is a lazy abbreviation of a description what you did and where you fail. "It does not work." is not a description that can be debugged by others.

Comment: I would say a video is better in some aspects. Especially since there's a specific sound my PC makes during bootlooping while the hard drive.